# Python Selenium - Text dissapeared when using javascript faster input

Tags: python, selenium, input, automated-tests

Hope you are doing well.

The default sendkey method of selenium is somehow slow and I learnt from here that I could use "driver.execute_script" to make faster input.

For most of the sites, ""driver.execute_script" works perfectly but recently I found that for some sites, "driver.execute_script" would input the text but if I press Enter or click anywhere afterward, the text will disspeared.

Below is sample of my code:

```
driver.get("https://www.apple.com/hk/en")
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Shopping Bag").click()
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign in").click()
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("recon-0-0").value="abc@abc.com"')
```

Does anybody knows whether it is restriction of the website or problem of my code?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this and essentially it is site-side. Seems like rather than an onValueChanged() they are using something like onInput(). Since changing the value directly is not an input action the attribute updates are not triggered (including the actual value). These include:
`.class=" form-textbox-input form-textbox-entered"`, `.aria-describedby=" signin-info-id"`, but most importantly--`.aria-invalid="false"`.

So, in short, changing the value directly makes it fail validation.

.send_keys() does work as expected

Comment: Yes. Send key works perfectly but the driver.execute_script failed. So I think there is no way to solve it out, thx for your reply :)